Flex doesn't scan as I expect
Here are some define and rules in my lex.l:
id        [_a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*
non_blank [^ \t\n]+

"("         { ECHO; }
")"         { ECHO; }
{id}        { printf("ID:%s ", yytext); }
{non_blank} { printf("INVALID:%s ", yytext); }
.           { ; }

And this is the text to be scanned:
main()
The result I want is:
ID:main ()
But the actual result I got is:
INVALID:main()
Since the order of rule {id} is higher then {non_blank}, I think "main" should be print first then "(" then ")".
I really don't know what the problem is.

If there is a parser attached, get rid of the non_blank rule and change the . rule to return yytext[0];, so the parser will view invalid characters as syntax errors. If there isn't a parser attached, get rid of the + in the non_blank rule, so that it doesn't maximally munch main() over the id rule, which will stop at main.
